# Power query calculate Percentage of changes in marks

Tags: excel, grouping, powerquery

I have a student data set in my excel. Let me show the data set here. I have n number of schools and marks obtained by the school in various years.

[image]

See, In the above data set, I want to calculate the Total marks percentage of changes over the previous two years.

```
Percentage of changes = (Current Year Total - Previous Year Total) / Previous Year Total * 100
```

Look at School S1, It doesn't have a Chemistry subject in 2020 but it is available in 2021. So When calculating the Current Year total I would like to avoid Chemistry from 2021. Its like Apple to Apple comparison. Also for 2020, Since there is no 2019 data available, the percentage of changes should be 0 or null for 2020.

I am expecting the following output,

[image]

How to do this in Power Query M language?

Comment: I would go with an if() to check both values are above 0 and calculate if true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With all the data loaded into Powerquery (data ... from table/range [x] headers) this seems to work if pasted into home... advanced editor...  Make sure to use your table name instead of Table1, like my sample

what I am basically doing is subtracting one from the year and merging the table on top of itself to find the value from the prior year. Then if prior year total is zero (missing subject), erase the value from the current year. Then I group on Year and School and do the calculation, with the total depending on lower of the Total and the revised-Total, since different years would sum different columns

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"School", type text}, {"Year", Int64.Type}, {"Subject", type text}, {"Total", Int64.Type}}),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([School] <> null)),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Prior Year", each [Year]-1),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Added Custom", {"School", "Subject", "Prior Year"}, #"Added Custom", {"School", "Subject", "Year"}, "Table2", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Table" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Table2", {"Total"}, {"PriorYearTotal"}),
#"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Table", "RevisedTotal", each if [PriorYearTotal]=null then 0 else [Total]),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Custom2", {"School", "Year"}, {
    {"Total", each if List.Sum([RevisedTotal])=0 then List.Sum([Total]) else if List.Sum([RevisedTotal])<List.Sum([Total]) then List.Sum([RevisedTotal]) else List.Sum([Total]), type nullable number},
    {"Percent", each (List.Sum([RevisedTotal])-List.Sum([PriorYearTotal]))/List.Sum([PriorYearTotal])*100, type nullable number}})
in #"Grouped Rows"
```

[image]

Comment: The answer to the above is correct. But Sometimes I need to add the missing subject of the previous year into the comparison. For Example, the Chemistry is missing for S1 and 2020. I wanted to include that as well for the comparison. I posted my question here. Could you please help me? 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72521965/power-query-comparing-product-profit-across-the-years